# Contenttool and Image

Tags: javascript

I'm using Contenttool : 
https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools

I would like to be able to change an image.

To do that, I click on the exiting image and upload a new one.

But, when I upload a file, width and height are at 1 x 1

[image]

And the image is not replaced by the new one. What I my doing wrong?

When I valid the page, my new image appear :

[image]

I've create a sample page :
http://portekoi.com/contentTool/test.html

Comment: The behaviour you're describing isn't what I experience using your test page? The test page works as expected for me accept on save the wrong image dimensions are sent back and so my image is set to 500 w x 600 h (when what I uploaded was 600 w x 400 h).

Comment: @AnthonyBlackshaw I just test again and my uploaded image is going below the image... http://desfurets.free.fr/photo/upload/lwgerkynzo7h250tq0emh4mj3b2dnj.jpg

Comment: So image uploads always insert currently, a feature to replace is on the roadmap.

Comment: @AnthonyBlackshaw Still on the roadmap?

Comment: @Portekol - yes in fact the internal version of CT we use already supports replace behaviour, however, the behaviour is added by external code at the moment - you can see it here https://github.com/GetmeUK/manhattan-js-content/tree/master/module/tools. These files provide new Image and Remove tools that allow image replacement (And removal for fixtures). This will definitely be standard feature for CT in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem directly come from the way contenttools manage images editing.

Instead of working with img tag, it use a div with a background image. The behavior between the two are completly different and is the source of a lot of issue related to image management.

The best solution to me would be to write a "real" image management plugin for contenttools that would deal with image editing in an.... img tag.

After that, you could just do a simple CSS rule like that :

img { max-width:100%; height:auto; } and your images would be responsive by default.